# Current post/product in Select options with selected - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress

I want to select specific drop down option to a selected post, for example the post is on Honda Fit, the the Drop Down should select Honda Fit automatically. The below code works fine but shows all posts instead of selecting specific to a post, e.g. `select guid from wp_posts where guid='$_GET['guid'] and post_type='product'`, I know it in a query logic but when i implement the query, the metabox just keeps loading and does nothing.

automotive_admin_help_message(__("This setting allows you to associate a WooCommerce product with a listing and show an Add to Cart section to allow users to checkout and purchase items.", "listings")); ?>

```
        <div class="tab_content">
            <div>
                <?php                                                                                                                               
                $current_woo_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, "woocommerce_integration_id", true);
                $args = array(
                    'post_type'      => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' => - 1                                         
                );
                $loop = get_posts( $args );
                if ( ! empty( $loop ) ) {
                    echo "<select name='woocommerce_integration_id' class='chosen-dropdown' style='width: 300px;'>";
                    echo "<option value=''>" . __( "No product association", "listings" ) . "</option>";
                    foreach ( $loop as $product ) {
                        $current_id = $product->ID;
                        echo "<option value='" . $current_id . "'" . selected( $current_id, $current_woo_id, false ) . ">" . $product->post_title . "</option>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                } else {
                    echo __( 'No products found', 'listings' );
                }
                wp_reset_query();
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

This is an image showing the all posts are being fetched [all posts image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojipb.png)

What I need is the drop down to select specific to that post [this is what i need it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSol4.png)

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: If you are post/product page then why you want this dropdown, in drop down only one product at a time will come so what is the use of that drop down?

Comment: Thank you for your response @dipmala, this drop down is an association between a listing and Woocommerce product, yes i want only one product at a time specific to that post.

Comment: Where your post is associated with post ?

Comment: @dipmala, there is a post in the database as "listing" and as a "product", for example Honda Fit=listing which shows up on the wordpress site as a post and Honda Fit as a product which is associated with the listing so that it can be bought. Hope that makes sense.